# Efficient way to insert record or ignore record when columns values are same, except dateTime column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table with a DateTime column. I want to avoid duplicate rows in my table on insertion. I have tried `INSERT IGNORE AND REPLACE`. However, since DateTime varies on every insertion, the records are duplicating.

How to check efficiently if other values are same then don't insert

My queries are:

`REPLACE into mytable (msisdn, tokenized_card_no, createddate, scheduletype, payment_for) values ('11', '11', now(), '12', '11');`

`insert IGNORE into ESB_AUTOPAYMENT (msisdn, tokenized_card_no, createddate, scheduletype, payment_for) values ('11', '11', now(), '12', '11');`

One way to do this, is to first **select** the record **if exist** then don't run the insert query. Is there any better solution?

[image]

I am using JDBC

Comment: Just form a unique key on the relevant column or columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL terms, this is called `MERGE` or `UPSERT` (which is a portmanteau of 'UPDATE or INSERT').

MySQL doesn't support it. You'll find that mysql doesn't support many things and really shouldn't be used in the first place, it's... not a good DB engine at all.

At any rate, you can still sort of do this: First make a unique index on everything except `createddate`, and then you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id`). Don't use IGNORE; that ignores all errors, not just primary key issues.

*) Using IGNORE is very common advice when searching the web for 'How do I UPSERT in MySQL', but, one of the problems of MySQL is that the community seems to be very careless about proper practices. **Do not use IGNORE**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what makes you row unique and define it as unique (you can also set multi columns).

After you will set it, the ignore / replace will work.